# Intersection of two shortest paths in connected weighted graph

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected directed weighted graph with non-negative weights
on edges.  Let $u,v,s,t$ be vertices in the graph $G$. I need to find an algorithm which in $O(|E|\log |V|)$ time checks if there is a vertex $w$ which lies in the shorthest path from $u$ to $v$ and $s$ to $t$.

My idea is to find a shortest path from $u$ to $v$ using Dijsktra for example, and then for every vertex $w_i$ in that path check if there is a shortest path from $s$ to $w_i$ and $w_i$ to $t$. This can be done in the seeked time using Dijkstra if I am correct. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: You want to run $\Theta (n) $ Dijkstras algorithm and wonder if that runs in $O ( m \log n ) $ time, is that correct?

Comment: What if there is a different $u\to v $ path that contains the intersection vertex?

Comment: Hint, can you find all vertices that are on some shortest path from $u$ to $v$?

Answer (score 1):

> My idea is to find a shortest path from $u$ to $v$ ...

As noted by Pål GD, it is not enough to find just one shortest path from $u$ to $v$ as a different shortest path might contain the wanted intersection vertex. We have to take into consideration all shortest paths from $u$ to $v$. Since we are only interested in the vertices, it is enough to  find all vertices that are on some shortest path from $u$ to $v$. Denote that set of vertices as $S(u,v)$, where $S$ is the shorthand for both "shortest" and "set".

**Characterization of $S(u,v)$:** Let $d(x,y)$ be the distance between vertex $x$ and $y$. $$x\in S(u,v) \Longleftrightarrow d(u,x)+d(x,v)=d(u,v).$$

It is immediate to prove both "if" and "only if" part.

Here is an wanted algorithm.

Run Dijkstra's algorithm with $u$ as source and with a priority queue such as described at [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue) to obtain function $d_u$ such that $d_u(x)=d(u,x)$ for all $x\in V$ in the form of a look-up table. Similarly, obtain function $d_v(x)$ such that $d_v(x)=d(x,v)$ for all $x\in V$ by running Dijkstra's algorithm on $G$ with all edges reversed and $v$ as source. Similarly, obtain $d_s(x)$ and $d_t(x)$. For each vertex $x$ in $V$, check whether $d_u(x)+d_v(x)=d_u(v)$ and $d_s(x)+d_t(x)=d_s(t)$. If we find one such vertex, the answer is yes; otherwise, the answer is no.

---

Here are several related exercises.

**Exercise 1.** Prove the correctness of the characterization of $S(u,v)$ as well as the correctness of the algorithm.

**Exercise 2.** Show that the above algorithm runs in $O(|E|\log |V|)$ time when the priority queue of Dijkstra's algorithm is implemented as a self-balancing binary search tree, binary heap, pairing heap, or Fibonacci heap.

**Exercise 3.** For each vertex $u$, let the shortest-path-index $d(u)$ be the number of ordered vertex pairs $(v_1,v_2)$ such that $u$ belongs to one of the shortest paths from $v_1$ to $v_2$. Let a path-center of $G$ be any vertex whose shortest-path-index is the maximum. Find an efficient algorithm that returns all path-centers.

Comment: A simpler algorithm is to find the shortest-path directed-tree from $u$. Then run BFS from $v$ on the the backward graph of that tree, which will find all vertices that are in the shortest paths of $G$ from $u$ to $v$.